# How to select item in combobox by key?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, combobox

I fill combobox using the following approach:

```
 //Setup data binding
            this.comboBox1.DataSource = dataSource;
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

            var dataSource2 = new List<Status>();
            dataSource2.Add(new Status()
            {
                Name = "Первый раз",
                Value = "1"
            });
            dataSource2.Add(new Status()
            {
                Name = "Повторно",
                Value = "2"
            });
```

Then I try to select item in combobox by key:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = data.payment;
```

Where `data.payment` is string "2";

How to select item in combobox by key?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `comboBox1.SelectedValue = data.payment;`

Comment: @OPV: I just had a project open where I could test a datasource bound ComboBox. Happy to report that all solutions suggested by Cody, Saheetharan and LarsTech work. comboBox.SelectedValue = "2" seems the most concise. If this is not working for you have you noticed that you are binding to variable datasource but populating var dataSource2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
comboBox.SelectIndex = comboBox.FindStringExact("Повторно")
```

or

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = "2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`SelectedValue`**,

```
comboBox.SelectedValue = "2"
```

or using **`Linq`**

```
   this.comboBox1.SelectedItem = dataSource2.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Value == "2");
```